# How to Simplify expression efficiently inside Power

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, expression-manipulation

How can I simplify `trivial` expressions under the `Power`?

Here is one example:

```
(z2p-z2p z3)^-ϵ
```

The expected output:

```
z2p^-ϵ (1 - z3)^-ϵ
```

Currently I am trying to look at the `FullForm` and decide the rule like below:

```
(z2p-z2p z3)^-ϵ /. Plus[x_,Times[-1,x_,y_]] -> x(1-y) //PowerExpand
```

However, how can I extend it to a general case where there could be multiple terms connected with `+-`? Or is there a better way to handle?

EDIT::

In a general scenario one would have factors multiplied with these kind of terms.

Example:

```
  expr= ((1 - z2p)^-e (1 - z3)^-e z3^-e (z2p - z2p z3)^-e)/
        ( z2p (-1 + z3)^2 (1 - z2p + z2p z3))
```

Basically how should one proceed to simplify/Factor out these terms?

Comment: `(-z2p)^-ϵ  (z3 - 1)^-ϵ` is an equally valid output.  What criterion should be used to decide between the two?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I understand this is indeed an ambiguity, but at least either of them is better that keeping the term in the original form (at least when I declare the variables as `Reals`). Even Mathematica loves to write `2 (1 - x) y // Simplify` as `-2 (-1 + x) y` (probably it takes less strings/internal operations to write second one? ). I personally dont like this output but this hurts less than the examples in this question. It is really annoying  that it can not do the simplification/Factor. I expected `PowerExpand` would have factor out everything using `Assumptions`  but not.

Comment: The case you just mentioned is an artifact of the canonical ordering that Mathematica inflexibly uses.

Answer (score 2):

Let us first introduce a function I will use:

```
factorMinus[expr_] := Module[{}, (-1)*HoldForm[Evaluate[-expr]]]
```

Here is your expression (I write it down in a simplified notation to make it more visible):

```
expr = (z2 - z2*z3)^-e;
```

Try this:

```
MapAt[factorMinus, MapAt[Factor, expr, {1}], {1, 3}] // 
  PowerExpand // ReleaseHold



 (*  z2^-e (1 - z3)^-e  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: This works for this example and even for any combination of arbitrary number of such `+-`. However one would definitely like to apply this in cases where not only single `Power` but multiple number of Powers are present, in such case this is difficult to apply.

Comment: I would not expect that one program could do such a work automatically for all possible expressions you meet. If you have a more complex expression, you will have to apply the analogous functions to all parts of your expression that you need to transform. It is not difficult, but requires some programming. By the way, application of the `factorMinus` is not always necessary, as you may have already noticed. If you have a very large expression I propose first to think do you really need to transform its terms and for what purpose.

Comment: yes probably have to go case by case.

Comment: @Boogeyman  Please provide an example of the expressions you actually wish to transform.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, please see the part after EDIT in the question

Answer (score 1):

In light of the recent edit to the question, consider a slightly more difficult case of two `Power`s:

```
test2 = (z2p - z2p z3)^-ϵ + (z2p1^2 - z2p1^2 z31^3)^-ϵ1
```

Define the function,

```
m[z1_, z2_] := Module[{fac}, fac = List @@ Factor[z1]; 
    If[fac[[1]] < 0, fac[[1 ;; 2]] = -fac[[1 ;; 2]]]; Times @@ (fac^z2)]
```

Then

```
test2 /. z1_^z2_ :> m[z1, z2]
(* (-z2p)^-ϵ (-1 + z3)^-ϵ + (-z2p1^2)^-ϵ1 (-1 + z31)^-ϵ1 (1 + z31 + z31^2)^-ϵ1 *)
```

Note that there is an inherent ambiguity in this process, and indeed in the question itself, namely what to do with an overall factor of `-1`.  I chose to attach it to the second factor, but other options are possible.

Comment: The EDIT part is the kind of expression I am sure everybody encounters. It is unfortunate there is no `simpler` way to handle this kind of expression. Even if I assume all variables are `Reals` or `Integers` (which I tried) this is not possible at least in a simpler fashion.

Comment: @Boogeyman  Yes, I am aware of no simpler method.  By the way, the example you added appears to be a different issue, how to simplify `(1 - z3)^-e/(-1 + z3)^2`.  In fact, `Simplify[(1 - z3)^-e/(-1 + z3)^2]` yields `(1 - z3)^(-2 - e)`, as I image you wish.  However, `Simplify[expr]` goes in a different direction.  Simplification can be difficult for a number of reasons.  Often, if is necessary to force `Simplify` to emphasize certain simplifications over others.